What means "can't resolve man7/groff_man.7"?
When I leave the explanation of the "man man" command on Ubuntu 24.04 ("q"), I see "man: can't resolve man7/groff_man.7". This is not happening with other comands like "man ls", for example. I did not find something specific about this in internet. What should I do to solve this? Thanks a lot!

You'd need to file a bug report to the developers of the man-package. Why do you think you need to fix it? man just output that message but quits.

... or possibly against the manpages package, since that appears to be what "owns" the erroneous /usr/share/man/man7/man.7.gz file (which apparently tries to source the groff_man.7 file)

Thank you both for your time and answers.

Even if there's nothing to do to solve it, "what it means" is still a fair question IMHO

This seems to be a bug in the manpages package. Specifically, it provides a man page for section 7
 7   Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages  and  conventions), e.g.
       man(7), groff(7), man-pages(7)

that instructs man to source a section 7 page named groff_man.7:
$ gzip -dc /usr/share/man/man7/man.7.gz
.so man7/groff_man.7

However the groff_man.7 page is not present unless the groff package is installed.
Probably the /usr/share/man/man7/man.7.gz file should be moved from the manpages package to the groff package. In the meantime, you can ignore the error - or tell man to only search in section 1 of the catalogue using man 1 man or man -s 1 man.

Thanks a lot for your answers and for sharing your knowledge.
